# JSON transform in typescript

Tags: json, angular, typescript, recursion

I'm quite newbie in this sort of stuffs. I have much bigger JSON like this:

```
{ "X": {
            "child1": {
                "k1": [],
                "k2": "12",
                "k3": "abc" 
            },
            "ver": {
                "dev1": {
                    "key1": "0x0100" 
                },
                "dev2": {
                    "key1": "0x0003",
                    "key2": "0x0300" 
                },
                "dev3": {
                    "key1": "0x990",
                    "key3": "0x0400",
                    "key2": "0x0100" 
                }}}}
```

As I would need to use angular tree component I need to transform the format above to something like this:

```
{name:X, children: [{name: child1, children: [{name: k1, children: [{name: []}]}]....
```

My question is how to go through the whole json to make this transformation? It should be probably possible via recursion, but I have never tried it.

My try for recursion:

```
recursive(obj) {
  if (obj instanceof String) {
    return {name: obj};
  } else if (obj instanceof Array) {
    const arr = [];
    obj.forEach(item => {
      arr.push({name: item})
      return arr;
    });
  } else {
    Object.keys(item => {
      return this.recursive(obj[item]);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at Object.keys to get the property names, try to "walk the tree" to creat your new array of objects. If you get stuck, update your original question with the code you wrote.

Comment: Well, that's something I tried. I'm just thinking how to iterate over whole JSON and how to find out I'm getting value and should go to the next key.

Comment: Maybe recursion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close, but you need to make sure to return something from each case of the `recursive` function.  Returning a value from a callback will not return it from the main function.  Also, `Object.keys` just returns an array of keys; if you want to iterate over them, you have to do that separately.  This would be my proposed solution:

```
recursive(name, obj) {
  if (typeof obj === "string") {
    return { name: name + ": " + obj };
  } else if (obj instanceof Array) {
    return { name: name, children: obj.map(item => this.recursive("", item)) };
  } else {
    return { name: name, children: Object.keys(obj).map(k => this.recursive(k, obj[k])) };
  }
}
```

You can adjust the way the names are handled as desired.